# IndexError: list index out of range when if len(listx[i]) > n

Tags: python, indexing, while-loop, range, out

I apologize in advance if my question is too basic. I have also tried to find answers in previous posts, but they are not exactly what I am looking for.

I am struggling with this exercise :

Write a program that analyzes all the elements of a word list one by one (for example
example: ['Jean', 'Maximilien', 'Brigitte', 'Sonia', 'Jean-Pierre', 'Sandra']) for
generate two new lists. One will contain words with less than 6 characters,
the other is words of 6 characters or more.

```
liste1 = ['Jean', 'Maximilien', 'Brigitte', 'Sonia', 'Jean-Pierre', 'Sandra']

moins6 = []
plus6 = []
i = 0 

while i <= 13 :
    
    if len(liste1[i]) > 6: 
        moins6.append(liste1[i])
        
    else:
        plus6.append(liste1[i])
    
    i +=1
```

I receive the error " IndexError: list index out of range "

Could you suggest me the right way to write it (with while loop)

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to your code your value of `i` is going from 0 to 13

while there are only 6 elements in your input list

so your value of `i` should go from 0 to 5

if you didn't know what your input size will be, you can use `len()` to find out

```
liste1 = ['Jean', 'Maximilien', 'Brigitte', 'Sonia', 'Jean-Pierre', 'Sandra']

moins6 = []
plus6 = []
i = 0 

while i < len(liste1) : # here is your error
    
    if len(liste1[i]) > 6: 
        moins6.append(liste1[i])
        
    else:
        plus6.append(liste1[i])
    
    i +=1 
print(liste1, moins6, plus6)
```

```
['Jean', 'Maximilien', 'Brigitte', 'Sonia', 'Jean-Pierre', 'Sandra'] 
['Maximilien', 'Brigitte', 'Jean-Pierre'] 
['Jean', 'Sonia', 'Sandra']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
liste1 = ['Jean', 'Maximilien', 'Brigitte', 'Sonia', 'Jean-Pierre', 'Sandra']

moins6 = []
plus6 = []

for word in liste1:
    if len(word) > 6:
        moins6.append(word)
    else: plus6.append(word)
print(moins6)
print(plus6)
```

### output:

```
['Maximilien', 'Brigitte', 'Jean-Pierre']
['Jean', 'Sonia', 'Sandra']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the list, find the `len` of each elem, and append it to the appropriate list:

```
liste1 = ['Jean', 'Maximilien', 'Brigitte', 'Sonia', 'Jean-Pierre', 'Sandra']

moins6 = []
plus6 = []

for elem in liste1:
    if len(elem) < 6:
        moins6.append(elem)
    else:
        plus6.append(elem)
        
print(plus6)
print(moins6)
```

OUTPUT:

```
['Maximilien', 'Brigitte', 'Jean-Pierre', 'Sandra']                                                                                                                          
['Jean', 'Sonia']
```